# Streams Processor key-value types

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm trying to implement a custom topology processing step implementing the [Processor](https://kafka.apache.org/31/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/api/Processor.html) interface and then adding an instance of my custom processor to the topology via *KStream.[process](https://kafka.apache.org/31/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#process(org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.api.ProcessorSupplier,java.lang.String...))*, however, this **always returns void** and only allows *Processor<KIn,VIn,**Void**,**Void**>* but I would like to add more processing steps after. My doubts are:

1. Can another processing step be added after *KStream.[process](https://kafka.apache.org/31/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#process(org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.api.ProcessorSupplier,java.lang.String...))*?
2. How should a custom processor with specific output types be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was recently addressed by [KIP-820](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-820%3A+Extend+KStream+process+with+new+Processor+API) (in [this PR](https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/11993)), by changing the signatures from:

```java
void KStream#process(ProcessorSupplier<K, V, Void, Void> processorSupplier, ...)
```

to

```java
KStream<KOut,VOut> KStream#process(ProcessorSupplier<K, V, KOut, VOut> processorSupplier, String... stateStoreNames)
```

It'll be available in version 3.3 from the looks of things

Comment: Is there a current work around for this by chance? @Luke

Comment: @user1238097 since I couldn’t find any snapshot repository for Kafka-streams, what I did was clone kafka and built the snapshot jars locally, and then copy them over to my `lib` folder (I’m using Scala and sbt). If you’re using gradle I’m sure you could also publish them to a local maven repository

Comment: I figure that was the only option since the ProcessorApi is terminal

Comment: @user1238097 I'm not sure what you mean with "the ProcessorApi is terminal". The workaround in my case was to use Processor API instead of Kafka Streams DSL indeed.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to add more steps, you'd add a new Processor to your Topology, after you've forwarded records through the context of a previous one.

In other words, define the init method with the output types for the ProcessorContext, and store the context as a field that you can use in the process method

Or you can use the DSL map method to do the same

Comment: It’s not possible to add a second processor to the topology via the DSL since `KStream.process` always returns void, and it requires the `ProcessorSupplier`’s output key and value to both be void too. It’s possible to do it manually via the Topology class, but then we lose access to the DSL methods